# Assigning a string literal to a char object

Tags: c++, char

I have a problem

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char a;
    a = "A";
    std::cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

```
1>c:\users\user\desktop\c++\bool 1\bool 1\bool 1.cpp(6): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

Any idea how to fix this? It should actually assign A to the char variable and display A right?

Comment: "Quick and short one" - What kind of title is that?

Comment: you has to change `"A"` to `'A'` (from double to single quotes)

Comment: @Mysticial: I fixed the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'A' and not "A".

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char a;
    a = 'A';
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay I got it, thanks for the info :) Will vote you up after I get 15 rep :)

Comment: It's a bit odd that you go at length explaining something that was not a problem in the original question, and then provide the solution to the actual problem as a footnote.  I mean, why did you choose to add an explanation of namespaces as your extra information, rather than how the overloading of `operator<<` works?  It's just as relevant.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley if you look at the edits you saw that i posted the answer first ;) but for the namespacing. -lazy developers- :) I don't get the 'downvote' i helped him and give some extra information, be happy guys, be happy. His problem is solved so stop the drama.

Comment: The code in the question, even in its original form, uses the `std` namespace *correctly*. Everything other than your last line (which you added later) is completely irrelevant to the question, and I'm going to go ahead and delete it.

Comment: @NathanSakoetoe: Sure (you beat me to it). (You might as well delete the words "The error solution:".)

Answer (score 3):

No, as the error message says `"A"` is an array of 2 chars, not a char. You want `'A'` instead.